# Pymongo: Identify if document returned by find_one_and_update is updated or inserted

Tags: python, mongodb, query-optimization, pymongo

I would like to know if the document returned by `find_one_and_update` is a new (inserted) or updated one.

My query is as follows:

```
predicted_user = db.predictions.find_one_and_update({'emp_name': user_name}, 
                                                    {'$currentDate': {"createdAt": True}}, 
                                                    upsert=True, 
                                                    return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)
```

predicted_user can be either:

1. A new user in the collection, due to `upsert`.
2. An old user whose `createdAt` has been updated, due to `update` command.

I want to achieve something like

```
if predicted_user is new:
      # Do send notifications.
else:
      # Don't send notifications.
```

Above can be achieved by multiple queries, but I would like to keep it to single(if possible).

Comment: It's the old one. `upsert=False` won't create a new document

Comment: @AlexBlex Ooops !! I need to make an edit in post. It was `upsert=True`

Comment: You can compare timestamp [from objectId](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html) with `createdAt`. Not very reliable for high load when you have concurrent updates of the same document. A more reliable option will require to introduce [document versioning](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/).

Comment: @AlexBlex As pointed out, timestamp comparison won't be helpful for me because I will be expecting burst of updates. So, will look at versioning instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement document versioning. E.g. if you keep document version in `_version` field, the update parameter can be:

```
{
    '$currentDate': { "createdAt": True }, 
    '$inc': { '_version': 1 }, 
    '$setOnInsert': { '_version': 0 }
}
```

Then you can check value of the _version. It will be 0 for upserted documents and anything above that for the updated ones.

You will need to update existing documents to add the field manually during deployment:

```
{'$set': { '_version': 1 }}
```